# ./retropie_setup.sh breaks packages

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, upgrade, updates

So I tried installing RetroPie on Ubuntu 18.04 using [this guide][1], but after running `./retropie_setup.sh`, I get these errors when trying to run `sudo apt uprade`:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-2.0-0 : Breaks: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 (!= 2.0.8+1) but 2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1 is installed
 libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libsdl2-2.0-0 (!= 2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1) but 2.0.8+1 is installed
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libsdl2-2.0-0 (= 2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1) but 2.0.8+1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` to try to fix this and I get more errors:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
 libsdl2-2.0-0
The following packages will be upgraded:
 libsdl2-2.0-0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 30 not upgraded.
19 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/378 kB of archives.
After this operation, 111 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 265018 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1) over (2.0.8+1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libsdl2-2.0-0/copyright', which is different from other instances of package libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.8+dfsg1-1ubuntu1.18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have the _unmet dependencies_ problem before running `./retropie_setup.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

I followed [these instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124290/apt-get-error-trying-to-overwrite-shared-filename-which-is-different-from-ot) and ran

```
sudo mv /usr/share/doc/libsdl2-2.0-0/copyright /usr/share/doc/libsdl2-2.0-0/copyright.backup
sudo apt --fix-broken install` and that seems to work.
```

Now the only message I get is

```
W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (150 vs 154).
Affected packages: libsdl2-dev:amd64
```